# Would ratio of intragroup distances make sense for comparing two distributions?

Tags: distributions, distance, wasserstein

Given two distributions `a` and `b`, we can assess the distance between them using e.g. the Wasserstein distance, Energy distance or Cohens'd. By dividing the metric values with the standard deviation of the combined distribution, we can make these metrics scale-invariant.

I wonder whether the following metric would make sense, too?

`distance(a + b) / mean[ distance(a) + distance(b) ]` , where `a+b` represents the combined distribution and `distance` could be

- the standard deviation
- the absolute distance of all pairs within a distribution
- the log-ratio of all pairs within a distribution

It's a simple and very likely not new idea, but I haven't came across it in literature or books and wonder how it relates to other metrics.

Comment: What is the context? What is the purpose of the comparison? Please add new infomation as an edit to the post!